# Laravel 5.1 route not expecting array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following routes:

```php
use NexCast\Domain\NiveisServico\NiveisServicoController;

Route::group(['prefix' => 'niveis-servico', 'name' => 'niveis-servico.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [NiveisServicoController::class, 'getData'])->name('get');
    Route::post('/', [NiveisServicoController::class, 'saveData'])->name('save');
    Route::delete('/', [NiveisServicoController::class, 'deleteData'])->name('delete');
});
```

However I am receiving the following error:

```
Type error: ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My personal recommendation is to upgrade that Laravel to, at least, 5.8. If it is an existing project and is difficult, do what you can to upgrade it as it performs better and have more stuff than 5.1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting happens because you're passing an array as the second parameter to the Route:: methods inside the group, but it expects a string instead. This is an example of what they should look like using your code:

```php
Route::get('/', 'NiveisServicoController@getData')->name('get');
```

You can find more information about routes in the [docs for the Laravel 5.1 version](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#named-routes).