# Type error: ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel. I am getting this Type Error when I change the following routings as below mentioned way.

My previous routing is as below.

web.php

```
Route::get('/add-teams',[
    'as'=>'teams.add',
    'uses'=>'TeamsController@addTeams'
]);
```

It works fine.
But I need to change that as this.

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\TeamsController;

Route::get('/add-teams', [TeamsController::class, 'addTeams'])->name("teams.add");
```

Then this error appears. "Type error: ReflectionFunction::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"
Please help me to solve this.

TeamsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Teams;

class TeamsController extends Controller
{

    public function saveTeams(Request $request){
        $team=new Teams();
        $team->team_name=$request->team_name;
        $team->description=$request->description;
        $team->save();

        return back()->with('team_added','Team added successfuly!');
     }
}
```

Comment: show TeamsController code

Comment: Do you have any `group` route as a parent for this route?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.1 route not expecting array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67743490/laravel-5-1-route-not-expecting-array)

Comment: what's your laravel version?

Comment: @JohnLobo I've edited the question with TeamsController code. Thanks

Comment: @MehediHassan its Laravel 5.5

Comment: @ÁlvaroZamora Its worked. But I want to know why I can't use the way I mentioned in above when creating routes

Comment: @pghasandi.the new routing method works in latest laravle verision.https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates